# Unrecognized VM option 'UnsyncloadClass'

Tags: java, jboss, jbossfuse

I am recieving the following error when running the command bin/fuse in the jboss-fuse-6.2.0.redhat-133 directory

Unrecognized VM option 'UnsyncloadClass'

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: JBoss is a Java software, nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: This belongs to ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using JDK 11.

The flag `UnsyncloadClass` (as well as `MustCallLoadClassInternal`) were [deprecated](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8140284). If they followed the protocol, they deprecated in Version 10, obsoleting them in 11, and removal in 12.